# Reactive query result in meteor publication?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

The goal of this publication is to publish problems that teams have "unlocked" and met the prerequisites for. It is working fine, but the publication does not update reactively when the team solves additional problems (adding to the team.solved field).

I have figured out that this is because the result of the Teams.findOne({}); query will not update reactively, and so the team.solved field never changes. Is there a better design that will allow it to update reactively or do I have to change it to Teams.find() and use .observeChanges() ?

```
Meteor.publish("problems", function () {
    if(!this.userId) return [];
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    if(!user.profile.team) return [];
    var team = Teams.findOne({_id:user.profile.team});
    return Problems.find({requirements: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: team.solved}}}});
});
```

If I'm using any unusual conventions here, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different packages design to address these types of problems, reywood:publish-composite and peerlibrary:reactive-publish come to mind .

To do this with peerlibrary:reactive publish, which is syntactically much simpler IMO, you would just wrap your code in an autorun, like so:

```
Meteor.publish("problems", function () {
    this.autorun(function() {  

      if(!this.userId) return [];

      var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);

      if(!user.profile.team) return [];

      var team = Teams.findOne({_id:user.profile.team});

      return Problems.find({requirements: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: team.solved}}}});

    });
});
```

https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/reactive-publish